# jqplot pie chart not rendering correctly.

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

Getting the log message: Diameter of pie too small, not rendering.

Then, it seems when I hover or click inside the page I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

```
    <link href="/Content/jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.jqplot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/Scripts/jqplot.pieRenderer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            //GetWeeklyProjectSummary();
            Test();
        });

        function Test() {
            var data = [["987 Project",74],["ABC Project",68],["XYZ project",26]];
            var plot1 = jQuery.jqplot('weeklyProjectSummary', [data],
                {
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        // Make this a pie chart.
                        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
                        rendererOptions: {
                            // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                            // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                            showDataLabels: true
                        }
                    },
                    legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
                }
              );
        }
    </script>
```

Here is the div its going into:

```
<div id="weeklyProjectSummary"></div>
```

Here is what I get on the page: [image: page output]

Let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had similar problem when using jqplot with blueprintcss - based on your screen capture I believe you are using blueprintcss.

Try removing the following line:

```
legend: { show: true, location: 'e' }
```

and see if it renders properly.

(Edit: More information here:

https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/issue/48/legends-doesnt-look-nice-when-using)

Comment: Hi,i m getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PieRenderer' of undefined" this issue can u please help me out. i added every thing.

Answer (score 3):

I added the following line in **my CSS file**:

**.jqplot-table-legend { width: auto; }**

to overload properties from the jqplot css file.

Worked for me.

Comment: This solves the same error with Foundation CSS on site.

Answer (score 0):

Your JQPlot chart definition seems correct. The pie renders correctly on my screen.

I do not see jquery.js or jquery.min.js included. Can you confirm you have a reference to this file in your code?

Also, confirm that all your js/css files are correctly referenced (you can use the [JSView Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsview/) to quickly confirm that they are indeed included).

Answer (score 0):

Include canvas.min.js. You can find it in examples in downloads. It worked for me with legend.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to extend the answer from [Amaud T](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2190416/arnaud-t):

I faced the same issue and I used the above answer, with some small modifications:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #chartComponentId table.jqplot-table-legend { width: auto !important;}
</style>
<div id="chartComponentId" class="chartComponent">
...
</div>
```

Due to the need of use *!important*, binding this stylesheet on a particular div objects prevents any side effects to other elements.